# Is powershell stopwatch buggy as I cannot get it to accurately time executions

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which runs thousands of commands that are logged onto the database, what I also do is log the start time and end time onto the database, one anomaly that I have noticed is that using the stopwatch functionality in powershell is giving me inaccurate timings.

This is how I use the stopwatch in my script.

```
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
#<a whole series of loops/code etc>
#when I need to log duration of a particular section
if ($stopwatch.IsRunning -eq $true) {$stopwatch.Restart()} else {$stopwatch.Start()}
#code here
invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance x -database y -query "insert into log_table values $($stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds) "
```

What is striking is that when I look at the database log doesn't the duration doesnt make sense.

In one example, according to what was logged on the table.

`start_time: 2022-11-01- 06:36:41.000`

`end_time: 2022-11-01.000`

The powershell script calculated the duration as 12 seconds, however looking at the timespan above it is clear to see that it is over 60 seconds.

Powershell version details below.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I am not sure if I am missing something here as my logging is incorrect and making troubleshooting  difficult.

Comment: `.TotalSeconds`. `.Seconds` is just the seconds part. I get this wrong all the time too, even though I know better now. :P

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Get-Date instead?

```
$StartTime = Get-Date

$Now = Get-Date

$Timer = $Now - $StartTime

$Timer.TotalSeconds
```

But `TotalSeconds` is what you need regardless.